# Pepper Host integration with a Dialogflow CX Project/AI Agent

Tags: dialogflow-cx, pepper

I have a Pepper running python and a Host subscription.  I built a chatbot on Dialogflow CX with a website as the source.  The chatbot works, but I can't figure out how to authenticate in the Pepper Management Portal Custom Chatbot settings. I've tried API keys.  Robotlab was not very helpful.  Anybody with some helpful guidance?

Built a project and custom chatbot agent in Dialogflow CX
Attempted to connect with the custom chatbox settings in robot management portal
Tried API keys but won't connect